# I want to change display property of this span class

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the display property of this **tooltip** when I hover on a span class
This is the **span** that the user will **hover**

```
<span class="video-title"></span>
```

This is the tooltip that will be shown

```
<span class="toolTip">Top 10 Latest</span>
```

And this is the **css style**

```
.toolTip{
    position:absolute;
    top:-34px;
    left:47px;
    z-index:100;
    display:none;
    padding:5px 6px 5px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:black 0 1px 0;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height:1
}
```

**The Question is that which is best for the display change? Javascript or Css

and how will I do this?**

Cheers!

Comment: In general, changing the display on hover is a bad practice, because it can move the placement of the object, which will end the hover. Then this will make the object move back to its origin al position, and so you'll see a flicker. This, I imagine, has contributed to the large number of downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in CSS fairly easily. If you place the tool tip `span` within the video title `span`, you can set it to `display:none` and have it change to `display: block` when the video title is hovered.

```
<span class="video-title">
    Title text here
    <span class="tooltip">Tooltip text here</span>
</span>

.video-title {position: relative}
.tooltip {display: none;}
.video-title:hover .tooltip {display: block; position: absolute;}
```

Obviously you would add your own styling and positioning to that. The tooltip should ideally be absolutely positioned so that it doesn't interfere with the layout of your page. Setting it's parent to `position: relative` ensures the tooltip is positioned in relation to its parent's position on the page.

Comment: Cool thanks,works will just adjust it to my own choice of style